# Cross-browser base64 webfonts support

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, stylesheet

[internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) **aborts** the `EOT` file loading progress sometimes, so the **font does not load** correctly.

1. There is a abstract solution with [**eotfast & mhtml**](http://nnucomputerwhiz.com/demos/fonts/demo-embed-eotfast.html), but it's not supported within IE7+8.
2. The regular `base64` method works pretty nice, but for IE9 *only*:

   > src: url('data:font/eot;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAggg=='); /*
   >   IE 9 */

What's the common solution, to **implement inline opentype webfonts** for [internet-explorer7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer7)+[internet-explorer8](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer8)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Data URLs are not supported for Internet Explorer 7
[More details on DataURL support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)

In this case, use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) to serve non DataURL font to IE7 and lower:

```
<!--[if (lte IE 7)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/fontface-ielt8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

#### Internet Explorer 8 has a DataURL size limit of 32KB

If your font doesn't show up in IE8, this may be the reason.
Then try to modify the font via [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) (expert mode) or another application to cut down the font size.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that your issue is not *problems implementing inline opentype webfonts for IE7+8* but rather the fact that *Internet Explorer seems to abort the EOT file loading progress sometimes*, I have to point out that fonts have to comply with [cross-origin resource sharing](http://dev.openfontlibrary.org/wiki/Web_Font_linking_and_Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Comment: +1 That's a good security approach, but definitely not the reason